# "plan should not reference subplan's variable" error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to update 2 columns in a table with values from another table

```
UPDATE transakcje t SET s_dzien = s_dzien0, s_cena = s_cena0
    FROM
        (SELECT c.price AS s_cena0, c.dzien AS s_dzien0 FROM ciagle c 
            WHERE c.dzien = t.k_dzien ORDER BY s_cena0 DESC LIMIT 1) AS zza;
```

But I got an error:

> plan should not reference subplan's variable.

DB structure is as simple as possible: `transakcje` has `k_dzien`, `k_cena`, `s_dzien`, `s_cena` and `ciagle` has fields `price`, `dzien`.

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3.

**Edit**

I want to update all records from `transakcje`.
For each row I must find one row from `ciagle` with same `dzien` and maximum `price` and save this `price` and `dzien` into `transakcje`.

In `ciagle` there are many rows with the same `dzien` (column is not distinct).

Comment: You should explain what your statement is meant to achieve in plain English. What are you trying to update exactly? Your code is ambiguous. Do you want to update a *single* row or one row with the highest `c.price` per `k_dzien` in `transakcje`?

Answer (score 3):

#### Problem

The form you had:

```
UPDATE tbl t
SET    ...
FROM (SELECT ... WHERE col = t.col LIMIT 1) sub
```

... is illegal to begin with. As the error message tells you, a subquery cannot reference the table in the `UPDATE` clause. Items in the `FROM` list generally cannot reference other items on the same level (except with [`LATERAL` in Postgres 9.3 or later](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html)). And the table in the `UPDATE` clause can never be referenced by subqueries in the `FROM` clause (and that hasn't changed in Postgres 9.3).

Even if that was possible the result would be nonsense for two reasons:

- The subquery with `LIMIT 1` produces exactly *one* row (total), while you obviously want a specific value per `dzien`:

  > one row from ciagle with same dzien
- Once you amend that and compute one price per `dzien`, you would end up with something like a cross join unless you add a `WHERE` condition to unambiguously join the result from the subquery to the table to be updated. Quoting [the manual on `UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html#AEN81927):

  > In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from
  >   the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be
  >   used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.

#### Solution

All of this taken into account your query could look like this:

```
UPDATE transakcje t
SET    s_dzien = c.dzien
     , s_cena  = c.price
FROM  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (dzien)
           dzien, price
    FROM   ciagle
    ORDER  BY dzien, price DESC
   ) c
WHERE t.k_dzien = c.dzien
AND  (t.s_dzien IS DISTINCT FROM c.dzien OR
      t.s_cena  IS DISTINCT FROM c.price)
```

- Get the highest price for every `dzien` in `ciagle` in a subquery with `DISTINCT ON`. Details:
  [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
  Like [@wildplasser commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719488/plan-should-not-reference-subplans-variable-error/19719765#comment29353109_19719765), if you all you need is the highest price, you could also use the aggregate function `max()` instead of `DISTINCT ON`:

  ```
  ...
  FROM  (
     SELECT dzien, max(price) AS price 
     FROM   ciagle
     GROUP  BY czien
     ) c
  ...
  ```
- `transakcje` ends up with the same value in `s_dzien` and `k_dzien` where related rows are present in `ciagle`.
- The added `WHERE` clause prevents empty updates, which you probably don't want: only cost and no effect (except for exotic special cases with triggers et al.) - a common oversight.

Comment: It would be good to explain why the OP's approach gave the error it did, as well as providing a working solution.

Comment: @Erwin: IMHO given `WHERE t.k_dzien = c.dzien` , the `AND  (t.s_dzien IS DISTINCT FROM c.dzien` term can never be true, so the where clause can be reduced to `WHERE t.k_dzien = c.dzien
AND  t.s_cena  IS DISTINCT FROM c.price` . BTW: Having `MAX(price)` in de subquery would be clearer (and less dependent on the postgres dialect).

Comment: @wildplasser: Note the difference between `k_dzien` and `s_dzien`. Not sure if the table design makes sense, but while it is that way, the `WHERE` condition makes sense. You are right about `max()`, but often people show simplified code and if we need more columns from `ciagle`, `max()` cannot replace `DISTINCT ON`.

Comment: I might have been confused by the columns names. (and maybe the OP might have been confused by his own naming, too )

Comment: @IMSoP: You are right, of course. I was a bit frustrated with the lack of information in the Q. Added a detailed explanation.